# Derived column results

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm an sql novice and have to Formulate an SQL query that lists all 5 columns from a QUALITY table and adds two more columns: ProductCode of the items produced in the batch, and a derived column BatchQuality that contains “Poor” if the batch is of poor quality (contains more than 1 defective item) and “Good” otherwise.

I'm pulling from 3 tables that I put in an oracle database: Production table(contains serialno, batchno, and productcode), Quality table (batchno, test1, test2, teste3, test4), and defective table (defectiveid, serialno).

I'm able to get 6 out of 7 columns by using the following:

```
select q.batchno, q.test1, q.test2, q.test3, q.test4, p.productcode_id 
from production p, defective d, quality q
where d.serialno = p.serialno
and p.batchno = q.batchno;
```

Any ideas on how to get the last column called batchquality that says if it's good or poor?  I'm thinking that I need a count function, but once I have that, how would I go about getting a new column that would state poor or good?
Appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It would be more helpful to show the table schemas and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is an inner join using an old, outdated implicit join in the `where` clause. I assume the `defective` table only contains a row for a product *if* there was a defect. Your inner join will always return defective parts only, never parts without defects. For that you need an outer join. Another reason to ditch the outdated implicit joins and use an explicit `JOIN` operator:

```
select q.batchno, q.test1, q.test2, q.test3, q.test4, p.productcode_id
from production p
  JOIN quality q ON p.batchno = q.batchno;
  LEFT JOIN defective d ON d.serialno = p.serialno
```

For products that do *not* have defects, the values for the columns from the `defective` table will be null. So to get a flag if a product had is "good" or "bad" you need to check if the value is null:

```
select q.batchno, q.test1, q.test2, q.test3, q.test4, p.productcode_id,
       case
          when d.serialno is null then 'good'
          else 'bad'
       as batch_quality
from production p
  JOIN quality q ON p.batchno = q.batchno;
  LEFT JOIN defective d ON d.serialno = p.serialno
```

Due to the nature of joins, the above statement will however repeat each row from the production table for each row in the `quality` and `defective` table. It is not clear to me if you want that or not.